# How do I stop the site content from being internally indexed?

Tags: 6, search

I have a Drupal 6 website, which is indexing the content for internal use. I don't use the Search module to search in the nodes, but The Search module is installed and enabled, since it seems to be required by the Google CSE module.

Is there anyway to stop Drupal indexing the content of the site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to admin/settings/search and set "Number of items to index per cron run" to 0.